# Long (>20million element) array summation in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and numpy so please excuse me if this problem is so rudimentary!
I have an array of negative values (it is sorted):

```
>>>neg
[ -1.53507843e+02  -1.53200012e+02  -1.43161987e+02 ...,  -6.37326136e-1 -3.97518490e-10  -3.73480691e-10]
>>>neg.shape
(12922508,)
```

I need to add this array to its duplicate (but with positive values) to find the standard deviation of the distribution averaged to zero. So I do the following:

```
>>>pos=-1*neg
>>>pos=pos[::-1] #Just to make it look symmetric for the display bellow!
>>>total=np.hstack((neg,pos))
>>>total
[-153.50784302 -153.20001221 -143.1619873  ...,  143.1619873   153.20001221  153.50784302]
>>>total.shape
(25845016,)
```

So far everything is very good, but the strange thing is that the sum of this new array is not zero:

```
>>>numpy.sum(total)
11610.6
```

The standard deviation is also not at all near what I was expecting but I guess the root of that problem is the same as this: Why doesn't the sum result in zero?

When I apply this method to a small array; for example [-5, -3, -2] the sum becomes zero. So I guess the problem lies in the length of the array (over 20million elements). Is there any way to deal with this problem?

If any one could help me on this I would be most grateful.

Comment: Does `math.fsum(total)` return `0`?

Comment: Yes it does!!! WOW!!! You mean I shouldn't have used numpy at all, I was in the misconception that numpy is the best tool for working on arrays!!! But looking in http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/math.html#module-math I don't see any tool for calculating the Standard Deviation. What would you propose?

Comment: No. `fsum()` is just for a sanity check that your code doesn't have some other bug other than loosing precision during summation. [`numpy.std()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) could be used for Standard Deviation. Try `np.std(total, dtype=np.float64)`.

Comment: I tried `np.std()` at first and it gives a value 10times more than I expected. Does this have to do with memory allocation in numpy? Based on the np.sum result we can see it only summed the later half of the array, probably the memory that numpy associates with arrays is smaller than the length of this array and so it has lost some of the initial elements.

Comment: I guess you are seeing overflow issue.  Note how `sum([1e308, 1, -1e308]) == 0.0` and `math.fsum([1e308, 1, -1e308]) == 1.0`

Comment: Thanks "wim", how would you propose to solve it?

Comment: @astroboy: have you used `dtype=np.float64` argument for `np.std()`?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: The source of these data was float32, when I added the term as you said the result didn't change: 0.105838159836, I also tried float64 but the change wasn't significant: 0.106921815313.

Comment: It helps to sort the data by its absolute value before doing a summation (especially in a case like this where you expect positive and negative contributions to cancel each other). It also helps to do partial sums first in chunks of, say 100000 or so, then add the partial sums together.

Comment: @Robert Kern: By this do you mean that I break up the array into smaller ones and knowing the mean (0.0) I find the separate necessary elements for standard deviation and find it manually? It isn't a bad idea but I was thinking there might be a more elegant way; for example increasing the memory use by numpy that might be the solution.

Comment: Memory is not the problem. The problem is because the partial sums get to be so large that individual elements are less than floating point precision compared to the partial sum. The recommendations I made are simply about implementing the sum accurately. My recommendation for implementing `std()` is to implement it manually, and use one of the accurate techniques for doing the sum that is part of the `std()` formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you get float roundoff problems from summing up many millions of equal-signed numbers. One possible way around this could be to mix positive and negative numbers in the combined array, so that any intermediate results while summing up always stay roughly within the same order of magnitude:

```
neg = -100*numpy.random.rand(20e6)
pos = -neg
combined = numpy.zeros(len(neg)+len(pos))
combined[::2] = neg
combined[1::2] = pos
```

Now `combined.sum()` should be pretty close to zero.

Maybe this approach will also help to improve the precision in the computation of the standard deviation.

Comment: The sum became exactly zero now, so did the mean which was also not zero. but the very strange thing is that the standard deviation did not change from what it was before. Unless `numpy.std()` uses another method to calculate the sum (for example in the `math.fsum()` module) this result is not acceptable because while `numpy.sum()` and `numpy.mean()` changed, `numpy.std()` didn't!!!!

Comment: You will need to implement `std()` yourself using the techniques we described to do the summations in the formula.

Comment: I wrote a program to calculate `std()` my self; finding the difference of each value with the average in packages of 10,000 elements, summing the results and finally dividing by the number of elements and finding the square root. It took about 15 minutes to calculate standard deviation for all >25million elements and it exactly found the same value as `numpy.std()` (that took a fraction of a second!). This data set was a test to my algorithm: as I said I knew the standard deviation from the beginning. I will check the source of that standard deviation to see if it is correct or not!

Comment: The value I was told for the standard deviation was after a 3sigma clipping, that I was not told of, after applying a 3sigma clipping I obtained exactly the value I wanted. Thank you very much everyone.