# Calculating average of the numbers in a .txt file using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains the numbers like this:

```
a: 0.8475    
b: 0.6178   
c: 0.6961    
d: 0.7565    
e: 0.7626    
f: 0.7556        
g: 0.7605    
h: 0.6932    
i: 0.7558    
j: 0.6526
```

I want to extract only the floating point numbers from this file and calculate the average. Here is my program so far,

```
fh = file.open('abc.txt')
for line in fh:
    line_pos = line.find(':')
    line = line[line_pos+1:]
    line = line.rstrip()
    sum = 0
    average = 0
    for ln in line:
        sum = sum + ln
    average = sum / len(line)

print average
```

Can anyone tell me, what is wrong with this code. Thanks

Comment: Note that the dupe only handles integers, so beware!

Comment: [use `math.fsum()` to avoid loosing precision](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8599333/4279). Consider `sum([1e20, 1, -1e20]) == 0.0 ` vs. `math.fsum([1e20,1,-1e20]) == 1.0`. `L = [float(line.split(':')[1]) for line in open('abc.txt')]; average = math.fsum(L) / len(L)`

Answer (score 2):

- Convert the line to `float` to do numeric addition.
- Initialize `sum` once (before the loop begin). Calculate the average after the loop once.
- len(line) will give you wrong number. The number of digitis + newline character count for the last number.
- Try to avoid using `str.find` + slicing. Using `str.split` is more readable.

---

```
with open('abc.txt') as fh:
    sum = 0
    numlines = 0
    for line in fh:
        n = line.split(':')[-1]
        sum += float(n)
        numlines += 1
    average = sum / numlines
print average
```

Comment: this might work, but is terribly unidiomatic in Python. Try to avoid using the `str.find` commands. In this case `num = float(line.split(":"))[-1]` is plenty

Comment: @AdamSmith, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `sum` addition in the wrong place, and you need to keep track of the number of lines, since you can't send a file object to `len()`. You will also have to cast the strings to `float`s. I'd recommend simply splitting on whitespace, as well. Finally, use the `with` construct to automatically close the file:

```
with open('abc.txt') as fh:
    sum = 0 # initialize here, outside the loop
    count = 0 # and a line counter
    for line in fh:
        count += 1 # increment the counter
        sum += float(line.split()[1]) # add here, not in a nested loop
    average = sum / count

    print average
```

Comment: This only happens to work since the delimiter is `: ` (note the trailing space. Probably safer to do `line.split(":")`

Comment: I'm not sure if the colon or the whitespace is the more reliable part of it, so I'm just assuming that they're both equally valid. Given the choice, a whitespace `split` is a bit cleaner-looking, so I went with that. But yes, if it turns out that the whitespace is arbitrary but the colon is not, then a change would be necessary.