# Write data stream to .txt, average values after n seconds, then clear text and repeat

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that writes my hyp_ft variable (continuously streamed once every second) to a text file, waits until 60 lines (1 minute) have been written, averages those 60 values, and then clears the text file and repeats.

I found some code from another post here and tried to incorporate this into mine, with an added if statement.

[Calculating average of the numbers in a .txt file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184348/calculating-average-of-the-numbers-in-a-txt-file-using-python)

Can someone look at this for me and tell me if this is correct? Thank you!

```
hyp_ft = (hyp_m*3.2800839) #hyp_ft is the value that is constantly publishing

f = open( 'hyp_ft.txt', 'a' )
f.write(str(hyp_ft) + '\n' )
f.close()

while 1:
    with open('hyp_ft.txt') as fh:
        sum = 0 # initialize here, outside the loop
        count = 0 # and a line counter

        for line in fh:
            count += 1 # increment the counter
            if count == 59
                sum += float(line) #convert the lines to floats

       average = sum / count
       print average

    fh.truncate()
    fh.close()
```

Comment: where are you waiting for 60 secs ?

Comment: You can use `time.sleep(1)` for 1 sec , and i think you should change `if count == 59` to `if count % 60 == 0`

Comment: @warl0ck since I'm having my program write to the text file once every second, I figure if I just have it wait until 60 lines have been written it would be the same as 60 seconds.

Comment: @t.m.adam okay t.m adam thank you for your suggestion I will try that it

Comment: @JAV thanks for the edits

Comment: not sure but that might be the issue, you might wanna try time.sleep(1) as take 1 line each time as @t.m.adam said

Comment: or alternatively you can wait for 60 secs and then read all 60 lines, do your calculations and clear the file

Comment: Okay, well I didn't post the full code, but basically my program is receiving GPS data once every second on its own and the hyp_ft variable is constantly being published. Sorry, but I'm not sure exactly where I should put the time.sleep(1).. is it before the "for line in fh'" line?

Comment: ok so it would be time.sleep(60)?

Comment: either that and after that just read all 60 lines or use `time.sleep(1)` and read single line after waiting

Comment: check the answer I posted, let me know if it works for you ..

Comment: Okay thank you so much. Will do.

Comment: @warl0ck hey I tried running both method 1 and 2 and it ran fine, but it only writes one value. I tried putting the lines f = open('hyp_ft.txt', 'a') line into a while loop but it gives me an "ValueError: I/O operation on a closed file"

Comment: writes one value as in prints 1 value ? can you be more precise what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @warl0ck sorry i should've been more clear. I was trying to have it store 60 values in a text file, take the average of those values, store that averaged value in a variable, then clear the text file and repeat this process every minute. But when I ran the code, it only stored the first value of hyp_ft without looping.

Comment: As the code is in `while true` which is always true as according to that it should continue printing your avg value.

Comment: Maybe because you might not be getting values in your text file after that have you checked if you are getting values again and again might this be a problem.

Comment: @warl0ck It only saves the first value that streams in, then it stops.

Comment: first stream as in it reads the file for the first time only ?

Comment: @warl0ck it saves only the first value that gets generated from my GPS device.

Comment: thats because as you can see we were writing the data only once to the file I thought there was some other script writing to the file, I'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `time.sleep()` function that might be the issue to your problem, try as:

```
import time
f = open( 'hyp_ft.txt', 'a' )
count = 0
while True:
    #hyp_ft is the value that is constantly publishing
    hyp_ft = (hyp_m*3.2800839) 
    # first time creating the file if it doesnt exists
    f.write(str(hyp_ft) + '\n' )
    count += 1

    if count == 60:
        f.close()
        with open('hyp_ft.txt') as fh:
            total = 0 # initialize here, outside the loop
            for line in fh:
                total += float(line) #convert the lines to floats
            average = total / (count) # as your count is still 59 not 60 what you actually want
            print average
            fh.truncate()
            fh.close()
            count = 0
        f = open( 'hyp_ft.txt', 'a' )
```

Here is the updated solution where you are continuously updating the value to the file updating the count value and as soon as you reach `60` if calculates the average and prints the value and continue doing the same.

And assuming you don't need the usage of this file outside of this code there is no need to create one, you can simply do something like:

```
def calc_distance(gps1, gps2):
    count = 0
    total = 0
    while True:
        gps1_lat = round(gps1.latitude, 6)
        gps1_lon = round(gps1.longitude, 6)
        gps2_lat = round(gps2.latitude, 6)
        gps2_lon = round(gps2.longitude, 6)
        delta_lat = (gps1_lat*(108000) - gps2_lat*(108000))
        delta_lon = (gps1_lon*(108000) - gps2_lon*(108000))
        hyp_m = (delta_lat**2 + delta_lon**2)**0.5
        hyp_ft = (hyp_m*3.2800839)
        total += hyp_ft
        pub = rospy.Publisher("gps_dist", Float32, queue_size=10)
        rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        rospy.loginfo("Distance is %s in ft.", hyp_ft)
        #        rospy.loginfo(hyp_ft)
        pub.publish(hyp_ft)
        rate.sleep()
        count += 1
        if(count == 60):
            print (total/count)
            total = 0
            count = 0
```

this is much efficient, check if this helps

Comment: Okay thank you so much. For some reason I was thinking line 0 would count as 1. Okay I'll test this out and see how it goes.

Comment: I have heard of Monte carlo method somewhere in my maths course thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

@warl0ck here is the entire function. What's happening here is that I'm trying to get GPS latitude and longitude values to calculate the distance between two GPS coordinates. It makes one calculation once every second and gives me the hyp_ft value. I'm trying to write 60 hyp_ft values, take the average of those 60 values, then clear the file and continue doing that for the next 60 values, repeatedly. As for the rospy lines, those are from the Robot Operating System (ROS) framework that this code uses to help it run.

When I run the code, it only saves the hyp_ft value, then after 60 seconds it gives me this error.

The error that I'm getting is:
fh.truncate()
"I/O operation on closed file"

```
    def calc_distance(gps1, gps2):
while 1:
    gps1_lat = round(gps1.latitude, 6)
    gps1_lon = round(gps1.longitude, 6)
    gps2_lat = round(gps2.latitude, 6)
    gps2_lon = round(gps2.longitude, 6)
    delta_lat = (gps1_lat*(108000) - gps2_lat*(108000))
    delta_lon = (gps1_lon*(108000) - gps2_lon*(108000))
    hyp_m = (delta_lat**2 + delta_lon**2)**0.5
    hyp_ft = (hyp_m*3.2800839)
        f = open( 'hyp_ft.txt', 'a' )
        try:
            f.write(str(hyp_ft) + '\n' )
        finally:
            f.close()

    pub = rospy.Publisher("gps_dist", Float32, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    rospy.loginfo("Distance is %s in ft.", hyp_ft)
    #        rospy.loginfo(hyp_ft)
    pub.publish(hyp_ft)
    rate.sleep()

    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        with open('hyp_ft.txt') as fh:
            sum = 0 # initialize here, outside the loop
            count = 0 # and a line counter

            for line in fh:
                count += 1 # increment the counter
                if count == 60:
                    sum += float(line) #convert the lines to floats
                    break # to come out of the for loop

            average = sum / count 
            print average

        fh.truncate()
        fh.close()``
```

Comment: not sure here why are you using file, when you can save the value in variable, it will be more efficient and faster not that it matters here since this is very small operation but still it's good practice.